# Java flight recorder programmatically parsing

Tags: java, parsing, jmc, java-mission-control, jfr

I'm trying to Parse JFR dump using JAVA.
I followed this blog, http://hirt.se/blog/?p=446 . 
But these methods are deprecated now. Is there any supported parsers for JFR to JAVA? if not can you point me is it possible to retrieve data from JFR dump?

Comment: See my SO answer on how to write a recursive descent parser: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245962/is-there-an-alternative-for-flex-bison-that-is-usable-on-8-bit-embedded-systems/2336769#2336769

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Klara](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37275705/1955702) mentioned, there is no officially supported parser. Hopefully the JFR parser will be supported officially in JDK 9. For now, you can use the APIs mentioned in [Hirt's blog](http://hirt.se/blog/?p=446). Don't worry about those being deprecated. :)

I have successfully used JFR parser in my [jfr-flame-graph](https://github.com/chrishantha/jfr-flame-graph) project. Please note that my project uses Maven and the JFR parsers are not available in Maven Central (or any other repository). Therefore the "Step 1" in the README is important and it'll [copy JFR parser jars](https://github.com/chrishantha/jfr-flame-graph/blob/master/install-mc-jars.sh) to a local repository and you can use those jars as dependencies in your [pom.xml](https://github.com/chrishantha/jfr-flame-graph/blob/master/pom.xml#L56-L126)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Most likely there will be a supported parser in JDK 9, which will look completely different, and the old parser will be removed. Just don't make any purchasing decisions based on this information.

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no supported parser.
There are however many people both inside and outside of Oracle who are using the parsers mentioned in that blog post quite successfully.

There will possibly be a supported parser in the future, there will certainly be changes to the parser, I'm just no sure if it will be "supported" or not. 
But the code you are writing now should work just fine with JDK 7 and 8 flight recordings, and will not will with JDK 9 recordings.