# Export Java Mission Control recording (jfr) in html report

Tags: html, report, jmc, jfr

Is it possible to export JFR recording in html report format ? scenario - I have to start jfr recording on the JVM for the duration of my performance testing. Once the testing is finished, I want to publish the JFR recording in HTML format.

Comment: See this question for info on how to parse the recordings yourself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37272867/java-flight-recorder-programatically-parsing. It is also possible to create a huge XML-file from a jfr recording (see http://isuru-perera.blogspot.co.uk/2015/05/flame-graphs-with-java-flight-recordings.html), depending on which info you want, it might be possible to create an XSLT transform, but I'm guessing it will be tricky.

Answer (score 1):

In the next version, JMC 6.0, the result of the automated analysis of the recording can be exported as HTML from within the UI. You will also be able to run the rules from the command line, and plug in your own analysis code (unsupported though). Building your own report generator will also be quite easy.

Comment: when will we have jmc 6 ? along with jdk 9 ?

Comment: Yes, JMC 6 will be released with JDK 9.

Comment: Hello Marcus, 
any chance to provide the syntax to generate the JFR report on JMC8?
On JMC6 it was:
java com.oracle.jmc.flightrecorder.rules.report.JfrRulesReport thefile.jfr -format html -min ok
But those classes aren't included in JMC8, I tried:
java -cp <the built core jars> org.openjdk.jmc.flightrecorder.rules.report.html.JfrHtmlRulesReport <file> [<outputfile>]
as posted at https://github.com/openjdk/jmc but I got a 16K HTML no matter the size of the JFR file, I can not see the result from a browser, just getting:
Show OK Results
Any idea?

Comment: Hi Mario! 

You have two alternatives. Either  org.openjdk.jmc.flightrecorder.rules.report.html.JfrHtmlRulesReport or org.openjdk.jmc.flightrecorder.rules.report.JfrRulesReport. You can experiment with them using https://github.com/thegreystone/jmc-jshell.

Comment: Hey Marcus, that jmc-shell is pretty cool and easier to operate, but I couldn't find any option to send the report to a file. Does that option exist? Any idea how to reach that? I appreciate your help.

Comment: Adding org.openjdk.jmc.flightrecorder.rules.jdk_8.1.0.qualifier.jar to the classpath made the trick. Thank you Marcus!!